# Limit of a sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=\arctan(\sin(x_n))$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This question involves a sequence $x_{n}$ which is defined as follow:
$x_{n+1}=g(x_{n})$ where  $0<x_{1}<\pi/2$ and where $g(x)=\arctan(\sin(x))$.

Prove that the sequence converges and find for which value.

**My approach**:  As we know that $0<x_{1}<\pi/2$ we can assume by induction that $0<x_{n}<\pi/2$ and then it follows that $\sin(x_{n})>0$ and so $0<\arctan(\sin(x_n))<\pi/2$ and therefore $0<x_{n+1}<\pi/2$.

now, I tried to do Lagrange's mean value theorem : all conditions apply and so there exists a $c\in[x_{n+1},x_{n}] $

$\displaystyle f'(c)= \frac{g(x_{n+1})-g(x_{n})}{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}=\frac{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}=\frac{\cos(c)}{1+\sin^2(c)}<\frac{1}{2}$

and also by the earlier induction $0<f'(c)$.

Now. I will denote a sequcne $a_{n}=x_{n+1}-x_{n} \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

We know that $\displaystyle \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}$
and therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(a_{n})=0\to  \lim_{n \to \infty}(x_{n+1}-x_{n})=0$.
I'm not even sure if it is the correct way but anyways I am still stuck and will appreciate any given help.

Comment: I doubt $\frac{\cos(c)}{1+\sin^2(c)}<\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @AnneBauval you're right! I meant $\leq 1$

Comment: But from $\le1$ you can derive nothing.

Comment: Since you meant $\le1$, please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Isn't your $f'(c)$ a typo for $g'(c)$? Moreover, that line would be clearer if rewritten$$\frac{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}=\frac{g(x_{n+1})-g(x_{n})}{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}=g'(c)=\frac{\cos(c)}{1+\sin^2(c)}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to prove $0<x_n<\frac{\pi}{2}$ by induction, which means ${x_n}$ is bounded.Because $\sin x_n<\tan x_n$ and $\arctan x$ is an increasing function, we have $x_{n+1}-x_n=\arctan\sin x_n-\arctan\tan x_n\leq 0$.Hence, the sequence converges.

For the value of the limit, you can prove $|x|>|\arctan\sin x|$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} $ with derivatives.Hence the value of limit is 0.